# Deleting certain segments of strings in R?

Tags: r, string, text, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

In R, suppose I have the following string:

```
x<-"The bank is going after bank one and pizza and corn."
```

I would like to delete all segments of the string before the **FINAL** time **bank** appears in the sentence, thus obtaining the string "one and pizza and corn." More generally, if I want to delete all text before the **final time a specific word appears** in a string, if there a way to do this?

Comment: are you interested in specific words? because the the example above, the word `and` is also repeated. If we were to delete, we would only remain with `corn`

Comment: yes i am interested in specific words; thank you for helping point this out.

Comment: try `stringr::str_remove(x, '^.*?(\\b\\w+ ).*\\1')`

Comment: or even `sub('^.*?(\\b\\w+ ).*?\\1', '', x, perl =TRUE)`

Comment: can you explain these statements in more detail? I don't really understand the syntax. Where is the part where I specify a certain word?

Comment: Check the solution below

Comment: Since `gsub` is greedy why not `gsub(".*bank +", "", x)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use group cature regex as shown below:

```
words <- "bank"
pat <- sprintf("^.*?(\\b%s\\b).*\\1 ?", paste0(words, collapse = "|"))
sub(pat, "", x, perl = TRUE)
```

Explanation `^` from begining the sentence, match `.*?` anything 0 or many times lazily until the first appearance of the bounded `word`. From here match greedily everything until you meet the word the last time. Replace everything with a empty string `''`